# org.flywaydb.core.internal.license.FlywayEnterpriseUpgradeRequiredException - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven, classnotfoundexception, flyway

In my `pom.xml`, I have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    <version>7.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Yet, when I run my web application, I get a `ClassNotFoundException` for `org.flywaydb.core.internal.license.FlywayEnterpriseUpgradeRequiredException`.

Please, help.

Comment: Which web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `FlywayEnterpriseUpgradeRequiredException` was removed at version 7, when "Enterprise" and "Pro" editions were merged into "Teams". It would appear your application code explicitly catches the v6 exception type, and therefore this needs to be updated.

The fully qualified class name includes `internal` which should indicate that it's not a formal part of the API and shouldn't be relied upon not to change (although at a major version, breaking API changes are possible in any case). Your application should catch the parent class `org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException` instead.